# Append one file into another file

Tags: vb.net, appendfile

I've been working on this for a bit and all the examples I've found have been to append a given string into the file, but I haven't been able to find any luck with appending a whole file at the end of a file. Everything's been using .appendAllText or appendText which doesn't suit my needs.

My files are `.sgm`. In my code I first grab all the sgm files, then I check if that file ends with _Ch#.

I'm ready to append the file to the master, but so far all I've been able to do is append the string text of the file name to the end of the master.

Your help is really appreciated.
Max

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click
    Dim searchDir As String = txtSGMFile.Text 'input field for user
    'Get all the sgm files in the directory specified
    Dim fndFiles = Directory.GetFiles(searchDir, "*.sgm")
    'Set up the regular expression you will make as the condition for the file
    Dim rx = New Regex(".*_Ch\d\.sgm")
    Dim ch1 = New Regex(".*_Ch[1]\.sgm")
    Dim existingFile = searchDir & "\Bld1_Master_Document.sgm"


    'Loop through each file found by the REGEX
    For Each file In fndFiles
        If rx.IsMatch(file) Then
            If ch1.IsMatch(file) Then
                Dim result = Path.GetFileName(file)
                Dim fileToCopy = searchDir & "\" & result

                'THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO APPEND fileToCopy INTO existingFile
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fileToCopy, existingFile)


                MessageBox.Show("File Copied")
            End If
            'MsgBox(file)
        End If
    Next file
    Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the .sgm mean they contain SGML?

Comment: Yes SGM mean SGML. But there just like text files that can be append into one and other provided they meet requirements

Comment: It looks to me that `Dim result = Path.GetFileName(file)` `Dim fileToCopy = searchDir & "\" & result` is a long way of doing `Dim fileToCopy = file` - or is there some other code which was omitted from the question? (Directory.GetFiles returns the full path as well as the filename.)

Comment: I put the full path in because the code will be run on multiple sub folders on our system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the file content into a string and then use AppendAllText like this:

```
Imports System.IO
' ...

Dim fileToCopy = Path.Combine(searchDir, result)

'THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO APPEND fileToCopy INTO existingFile
Dim fileContent = File.ReadAllText(fileToCopy)

File.AppendAllText(existingFile, fileContent)
```

Using [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a bit better than concatenating strings.

Comment: depending on the size of the file this might not be feasible to load the entire file into memory. A more general approach would be to read chunks of the file.

Comment: @FalcoGer Let's worry about that if it actually happens. We should also check that there is enough free disk space.

Comment: This was great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can literally append all bytes using an approach like this:

```
Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(existingFile, IO.FileMode.Append)
    Dim bytes() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToCopy)
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
End Using
```