# VB.Net Search for text and replace with file content

Tags: vb.net

This is a follow on question to a post I made. [Append one file into another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339930/append-one-file-into-another-file/55340628#55340628)

I need to search the master document for entities `"&CH1.sgm"` to `"&CH33.sgm"`,
mark where they are in the master document and replace the entity call with the matching file `"Chapter1.sgm"` found in "fnFiles". I can change the file names and entities to anything if that will help.

My code copies the text of a file and appends it to the bottom of the master_document.sgm. But now I need it to be more intelligent. Search the Master document for entity markers, then replace that entity marker with that file contents match. The file number and entity number match up. e.g.(&CH1; and Bld1_Ch1.sgm)

```
Private Sub btnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click
    Dim searchDir As String = txtSGMFile.Text 'Input field from form
    Dim masterFile = "Bld1_Master_Document.sgm"
    Dim existingFileMaster = Path.Combine(searchDir, masterFile)

    'Read all lines of the Master Document
    Dim strMasterDoc = File.ReadAllText(existingFileMaster) '// add each line as String Array.

    '?search strMasterDoc for entities &Ch1.sgm
    '?replace entity name "&Ch1.sgm" with content of file "Bld1_Ch1.sgm" this content if found below
    '? do I use a book mark? Replace function?


    'Get all the sgm files in the directory specified
    Dim fndFiles = Directory.GetFiles(searchDir, "*.sgm")
    'Set up the regular expression you will make as the condition for the file
    Dim rx = New Regex(".*_Ch\d\.sgm")
    Dim ch1 = New Regex(".*_Ch[1]\.sgm")
    'Use path.combine for concatenatin directory together

    'Loop through each file found by the REGEX
    For Each fileNo In fndFiles
        If rx.IsMatch(fileNo) Then
            If ch1.IsMatch(fileNo) Then
                Dim result = Path.GetFileName(fileNo)
                'Use path.combine for concatenatin directory together
                Dim fileToCopy = Path.Combine(searchDir, result)

                'This is the file we want to copy into MasterBuild but at specific location.
                'match &ch1.sgm inside strMasterDoc

                Dim fileContent = File.ReadAllText(fileToCopy)

                'Search master file for entity match then append all content of fileContent


                File.AppendAllText(existingFileMaster, fileContent)

                MessageBox.Show("File Copied")
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: IMO, you should use a Regex to find matching patterns inside your Master Document (`&CH1.sgm`, `&CH2.sgm` etc.). `Regex.Matches` returns a collection of matches which reports the index position inside the string where the match was found and also (among other things) the length of the matched pattern. You can then use these informations to `Insert` a string (corresponding to an external file content) in the referenced positions. Use the pattern found to load the related Text file. Use a `StringBuilder` instead of a simple `string` to hold the files content.

Comment: It looks like you have just pasted the fixed code from the other question, but I don't see a trace of an attempt to achieve your new requirement. Try to solve it yourself and come back with any specific issues you encounter.

Comment: I have been working on it and searching the net for an answer. What I posted was the cleanest version of my file so you wouldn't see all my previous attempts and mistakes. I wouldn't just paste code an expect everyone to write it for me. But I appreciate your wanting to keep me honest. Max

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (big if), you want to replace the the text of the abbreviated chapter name in the master file with the contents of the file it refers to at the spot where the abbreviation is found.

I made a class to handle the details.

```
Private Sub btnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnImport.Click
    'Add a FolderBrowseDialog to your form designer
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim searchDir As String = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    Dim existingFileMaster = Path.Combine(searchDir, "Bld1_Master_Document.sgm")
    Dim lstFileChanges = CreateList(searchDir)
    'The following method does NOT return an array of lines
    Dim strMasterDoc = File.ReadAllText(existingFileMaster)
    For Each fc In lstFileChanges
        strMasterDoc = strMasterDoc.Replace(fc.OldString, fc.NewString)
    Next
    File.WriteAllText(existingFileMaster, strMasterDoc)
End Sub

Private Function CreateList(selectedPath As String) As List(Of FileChanges)
    Dim lstFC As New List(Of FileChanges)
    For i = 1 To lstFC.Count
        Dim fc As New FileChanges
        fc.OldString = $"&CH{i}.sgm"
        fc.FileName = $"Chapter{i}.sgm"
        fc.NewString = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(selectedPath, fc.FileName))
        lstFC.Add(fc)
    Next
    Return lstFC
End Function

Public Class FileChanges
    Public Property OldString As String '&CH1.sgm 
    Public Property FileName As String 'Chapter1.sgm
    Public Property NewString As String 'Contents of Chapter1.sgm, the string to insert
End Class
```

Testing .Replace

```
Dim s As String = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."
s = s.Replace("fox", "foxes")
MessageBox.Show(s)
```

Comment: `strMasterDoc = strMasterDoc.Replace(fc.OldString, fc.NewString)`. `For i = 1 To 33`? Uhmm. So, you counted them beforehand? (I know, the question says that..., but...)

Comment: @Mary thank you this was great, but it's not replacing the text in  in strMasterDoc.Replace(fc.OldString, fc.NewString). If I do a dialogue box check to see what's in each variable. It's right it's grabbing the right text.

Comment: strMasterDoc count is infinite. I just put 33 as a jumping off point

Comment: @Jimi changed to lstFC.Count. Thanks

Comment: @MaxineHammett changed 33 to lstFC.Count

Comment: @Mary I'm still uncertain why line "Dim strMasterDoc.Replace(fc.OldString, fc.NewString) isn't working. All the data get pulled into the variables, just the replace seems to be broken. Thank you for the help. Maxine

Comment: @Maxine Hammett See the first comment. `string.Replace()` is a function.

Comment: @MaxineHammett , yes, I need to correct. Have to do a few other things will get back to you.

Comment: @Jimi Yes I caught that and changed it, but the replace function still isn't working

Comment: See update to the line `strMasterDoc.Replace(fc.OldString, fc.NewString)` The correct version is `strMasterDoc = strMasterDoc.Replace(fc.OldString, fc.NewString)` So sorry!

Comment: `lstFC` will be `0` at that point. You haven't parsed the Document, yet, so you don't know how many elements you should substitute, that's why I suggested `Regex.Matches` in the comments. (Hasty downvote, don't give up :)

Comment: Not giving up :-) @Mary I'm still not getting results with that replace. I added MsgBox("strMasterDoc   " & strMasterDoc) so I could see what's in the file and it's the original file without the replace changes.

Comment: Argh! I couldn't test and so it is full of bugs. :-) Again, let me see where I can conveniently get a count to replace that 33. But, the other bug should be fixed.

Comment: @Mary Oh I feel so stupid the file entity is $"&CH{i};" with a semi-colon not .sgm. I made the change to the fc.OldString = $"&CH{i};" But the code still isn't working

Comment: I think `Dim count As Integer = Directory.GetFiles(selectedPath, "*.smg").Length`  then `For i = 1 To count` might come close but the Master file seems to be in the same directory so maybe should be `,Lenght -1`

Comment: If this is it I will add the latest fix to the code after you comment.

Comment: Thank you Mary but the replace still isn’t working @Mary

Comment: Darn, I posted a bit of a test to demonstrate the use of `.Replace`

Comment: @Mary I just made it home. I’ll test first thing in the morning. Thank you for all the help on this

Comment: @Mary the replace code for testing works. But the strMasterDoc doesn't.

Comment: This is a real basic question but one I don't want to over look. In my code I have Public Class Form1. Inside it is Private Sub btnImportClick, AND Private Function CreateList. Then a new Publid Class FileChanges. Do I have this order right? or does the function need to exist outside the main Class? Thanks for your patience. Maxine @Mary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190703/discussion-between-maxine-hammett-and-mary).

Comment: @Mary are you out there? Is anyone available to help me with this problem?